# Context initialization failed and Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': and Error in userDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement log in authentication using spring security userDeatilsService and I have tried the following things so far,

userdetailsService:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao; 

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user=userDao.findUserByName(username);

            if(user!=null)
            {


                String password=user.getPassowrd();

                boolean enabled=user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
                boolean accountNonExpired = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
                boolean credentialsNonExpired = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
                boolean accountNonLocked = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);

                //populate user roles

                Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                for(Role role : user.getRoles()){

                    authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getRoleName()));
                }

                //create spring security object
                org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User securityUser = new 
                    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);

                    return securityUser;
            }else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found !!!");
            }
```

-servlet.xml:

```
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.dz.hrportal.controller" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>

    </bean>
    <bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/CSS/" />
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portal"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
   </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.assessme.com.controller.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

Web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

-security.xml:

```
    <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
            <security:form-login  login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/admin" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />        
    </security:http>
  <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></property>
 </bean>
 <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                    <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
            </list>
        </property>
  </bean>
    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.dz.hrportal.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>
     <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5"></security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dz.hrportal.dao,com.dz.hrportal.dao.impl,com.dz.hrportal.service" />
```

and I am getting the following errors:
complete stack trace:

**UPDATE:**
UserDao:

```
public interface UserDao {

    void addUser(User user);

    void editUser(User user);

    void deleteUser(int userId);

    User findUser(int userId);

    User findUserByName(String username);

    List<User> getAllUsers();

}
```

and UserDaoImple;

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory session;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {

        session.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void editUser(User user) {
        session.getCurrentSession().update(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(int UserId) {
        session.getCurrentSession().delete(findUser(UserId));
    }

    @Override
    public User findUser(int userId) {

        return (User) session.getCurrentSession().get(User.class,userId);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserByName(String username) {
        Criteria criteria=session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        return (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {

        return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
    }
```

Stack trace:

```
17:26:09,810 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:334 - Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'sessionFactory'
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:377)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:278)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1206)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1246)
    ... 38 more
17:26:09,814 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:334 - Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'transactionManager'
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] for bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:377)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:278)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1206)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1246)
```

Comment: Where is UserDao, because I don't see it? (not in XML and not in Java code)

Comment: @andrei-stefan,I have added it in xml file please let me edit the question please wait.

Comment: I still don't see UserDao :-).

Comment: @andrei-stefan,I have updated the question please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the bug. Actually the org.springframework.transaction-3.1.RELEASE.jar was missing so,added and now it seems working.

Answer (score 2):

add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring is not able to  create bean for 
`com.dz.hrportal.dao.UserDao` why because you did not specify the package of UserDao class in `<context:component-scan base-package="com.hrportal.controller" />`, since you have given  `com.hrportal.controller` spring will create beans only for the classes inside that package and will not create beans for the  classes inside package `com.dz.hrportal.dao.UserDao`. change this tag to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.hrportal" />`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use spring much, but judge from the stack trace, spring cannot find userDao's implementation.

Have you specify the implement bean for userDao, or use auto component scan for the correct java package?